# Homophonia, or: U can't touch this

Tags: pronunciation, homophones

[image: Worst case example?]

In case it isn't obvious: ewe,yew,Jew,U,hew,Hugh,hue,you. Given that English is not [Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion-Eating_Poet_in_the_Stone_Den), this must be a record. But note that I'm a German and not familiar with "standard" English pronunciation. (Evidently I could just look up the phonetic transcription in a dictionary, but I'm not convinced, especially considering the multitude of English dialects.)

Thus: Which of these are true homophones, and which aren't (j vs. dj etc.)? And, since this was just a random but blatant example I came up with: Are there fine differences in English pronunciation a native speaker can hear, but aren't accounted by International Phonetic spelling?

(Context: I'm a fan of British comedy, but without subtitles I'm often lost, especially when it comes to puns. I just say "Four Candles"...)

Comment: I believe there are regional dialects where the h is silent in "Hugh", "hue", "hew", but I don't think any native speaker would pronounce "Jew" as "you".

Comment: The way homophony could occur would be if "you" combined with a preceding /t/ to produce an affricate. E.g. "what you" can become /wɒt͡ʃu:/ or /wɒdʒu:/ in casual speech.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different dialects of English, and even regional accents within those can greatly affect pronunciation. But, enunciated correctly, there should be a clear audible difference between *ju*, *yju* and *dju*.

- **Yew, ewe, U,** and **you** are homophones.
- **Hew, Hugh** and **hue** are homophones
- **Jew** is not a homophone of any of the above.*

**NB some British English speakers pronounce the word "dew" in a way that sounds very similar to "Jew".*

That said, for the purposes of *puns*, you can have 'near rhymes' and you can clearly have 'near homophones'. There is a potential pun in any context where one word could be mistaken for another.

Comment: Just to clarify: "Homophones" means "exact", i.e., in conversation meaning can be deduced *only* from context (ignoring the possibility that dialects might as well "split" homophones)?